# Vector (Vector Foo) -> (Ptr (Ptr Foo) -> IO a) -> IO a?

Tags: haskell, vector, ffi

I am making a simple wrapper for a c library that needs to have a list of vectors passed to it. It takes an array of pointers to arrays. To make a nice interface I'd like to have Vector (or list) of Vectors, but I can't really find out how to do this in idiomatic haskell. (Or any other way than memcopying stuff around).

What I'm looking for is something like

```
Vector (Vector Foo) -> (Ptr (Ptr Foo) -> IO a) -> IO a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: hCsound doesn't deal with this exact case, so I've added a full example below.

You might want to look at my package [hCsound](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hCsound) ([darcs repo](http://www.tiresiaspress.us/haskell/hCsound/)), which has to deal with a very similar case.

Note that it's very important that the C library doesn't **modify** the arrays used by a `Data.Vector.Storable.Vector`.  If you do need to modify the data, you should copy the old data first, modify the array through the ffi, and finally wrap the pointers into a new Vector.

Here's the code.  As was pointed out in a comment, `Data.Vector.Storable.Vector` doesn't have a Storable instance itself, so you'll need the outer vector to be a `Data.Vector.Vector`.

```
import Foreign.Storable
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.Marshal.Array

import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as S
import Data.Vector.Storable.Internal

withPtrArray v f = do
  let vs = V.map S.unsafeToForeignPtr v   -- (ForeignPtr, Offset, Length)
  ptrV = V.toList $ V.map (\(fp,off,_) -> offsetToPtr fp off) vs
  res <- withArray ptrV f
  V.mapM_ (\(fp,_,_) -> touchForeignPtr fp) vs
  return res
```

Note the array is allocated by `withArray`, so it's automatically gc'd after the function returns.

These arrays aren't null-terminated, so you'll need to make sure that the length is passed to the C function by some other method.

`withForeignPtr` isn't used.  Instead, `touchForeignPtr` is called to ensure that the ForeignPtr's aren't deallocated before the C function is finished.  In order to use `withForeignPtr`, you'd need to nest calls for each internal vector.  That's what the `nest` function in the hCsound code does.  It's rather more complicated than just calling `touchForeignPtr`.

Comment: Could you give me name of specific function to look at?

Comment: @aleator: I may have been wrong a bit.  The closest is probably `Sound.Csound.Foreign.withStringList`, but that uses Strings, not Vectors.  I thought that the input/output functions were nested, but they aren't.  Although it's pretty close to what you have to do.  The weird function `nest` is actually pretty important for this; I'll try to give a real update soon.

Comment: @aleator: real answer provided.  This is actually quite an intricate question.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're passing to a C function, you should use `Data.Vector.Storable`.  You can't just pass a vector of vectors of `Storable` because that will not be a vector merely of pointers to arrays, it also includes size and offset information.

if the argument to the C function is, say, `int myCFunc(foo** arrays, int sz)` then the following code should work:

```
import Data.Vector.Storable
import Foreign.Storable
import Foreign.ForeignPtr

withCFunction :: Storable a =>         -- ^ Storable so compatible with C
                Vector (Vector a)      -- ^ vector of vectors
              -> (Ptr (Ptr a) -> IO b) -- ^ C function wrapped by FFI
              -> IO b
withCFunction v f = do
  vs <- mapVectorM (\x -> let (fp,_,_) = unsafeToForeignPtr x 
                          in unsafeForeignPtrToPtr fp) v
  mapVectorM_ (\x -> let (tfp,_,_) = unsafeToForeignPtr x
                     in touchForeignPtr tfp) vs
  let (vfp,_,_) =  unsafeToForeignPtr vs
  withForeignPtr vfp $ \p -> f p
```

Comment: IIRC, when unwrapping storable vectors the foreign ptr is just a handle for memory management purposes; the actual vector may be a slice of the memory the to which the ForeignPtr points.  There's also a Ptr in there that points to the actual start of the vector, and the usual idiom is to `withForeignPtr fp $ \_ -> foo`, where `foo` uses the Ptr instead of the contents of the ForeignPtr.  The proper way to do this would be significantly more complex, I believe.

Comment: Also, I don't believe that Storable vectors have a Storable instance themselves, so unless I'm mistaken (which is, of course, quite possible) you can't create a `Vector (Vector a)` in the first place.

Comment: @augustss: I don't disagree, but that's usually the case when interfacing with C.  It's easy to violate referential transparency, which is Really Bad.

Comment: @John L But I worry about doing unsafe things with foreign pointers, that can make things go very wrong.

Comment: @augustss: Yes, it certainly can.  It would be nice if, when people include `unsafe*` functions in an interface, they document what's unsafe about it.  For Vector in particular, you can't modify the data pointed to by the foreign pointer.  I know that, and you know that, but it really should be documented.  And violating that rule leads to subtle, strange errors, where the problem is not necessarily obvious (speaking from experience here).  So I agree with you, but since I don't know a better way to achieve the same performance sometimes I'm stuck doing this.

Comment: @mokus, the `withForeignPtr` idiom is indeed used, on the last line.  You are correct that there is no library `Storable (Vector a)` instance, but it is not too hard to code up.  The `ForeignPtr` is a special construct around a vanilla `Ptr` which includes finaliser code.  This is why `unsafeForeignPtrToPtr` is used.  It generates the vanilla `Ptr`s needed by the C code.  Modulo lack of library `Storable (Vector a)` instance, this **is** the correct way.

Comment: @augustss: yes, there is much unsafe here.  The perils of interfacing to an unsafe language require it.

Comment: @John L: indeed modifying the values of a `Vector` is bad.  This is the reason for the 'idiom' `withForeignPtr`.  Haskell is referentially transparent when pure (not in the IO monad and stuff) which means that most often (and only in those cases), the client doesn't need to know about the uses of `unsafe*`.

Comment: @augustss never mind about the interface being unsafe. The target lib segfaults if instructed to load a missing file..

Comment: @vivian: I know what a ForeignPtr is.  What I was getting at was that the ForeignPtr doesn't point directly to the vector's contents.  It points to a buffer and gives an offset within that buffer, which is sometimes nonzero.  So using the Ptr "inside" the ForeignPtr isn't correct unless you offset it first.  Also, how can a Storable (Vector a) instance possibly implement sizeof?  Part of sizeof's spec is that it does not touch the value of its argument (because it's used to preallocate).  The vector library depends on that fact, as do most other functions using Storable.

Comment: @vivian: `withForeignPtr` doesn't solve the issue I'm referring to.  The problem is that the Vector uses the data held by the ForeignPtr for storage.  If you modify that data (via withForeignPtr, in IO), you've changed the data held by the Vector, meaning it's no longer referentially transparent.  That's why these `unsafe*` functions are **unsafe**; by giving the client access to the raw pointer referential transparency can be violated.  Which means that GHC will likely as not generate incorrect code.